# Measure user time or system time in Ruby without Benchmark or time

Tags: ruby, time, benchmarking, measurement, systemtime

Since I'm doing some time measurements at the moment, I wondered if it is possible to measure the user time or system time without using the `Benchmark` class or the command line utility `time`.

Using the `Time` class only reveals the wall clock time, not system and user time, however I'm looking for a solution which has the same flexibility, e.g.

```
time = TimeUtility.now
# some code
user, system, real = TimeUtility.now - time
```

The reason is that I somehow dislike `Benchmark`, since it cannot return numbers only (*EDIT: I was wrong - it can. See answers below.*). Sure, I could parse the output, but that doesn't feels right. The `time` utility from *NIX systems should solve my problem as well, but I wanted to know if there already is some kind of wrapper implemented in Ruby so I don't need to make these system calls by myself.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I re-read the Benchmark documentation and saw that it has a method named `measure`. This method does exactly what I want: Measure the time your code needs and returning an object which contains user time, system time, system time of childrens etc. It is as easy as

```
require 'benchmark'
measurement = Benchmark.measure do
  # your code goes here
end
```

In the process I found out that you can add custom rows to the Benchmark output. You can use this to get the best of both worlds (custom time measurements and a nice output at the end) as follows:

```
require 'benchmark'

measurements = []
10.times { measurements << Benchmark.measure { 1_000_000.times { a = "1" } } }

# measurements.sum or measurements.inject(0){...} does not work, since the
# array contains Benchmark instances, which cannot be coerced into Fixnum's
# Array#sum will work if you are using Rails
sum = measurements.inject(nil) { |sum, t| sum.nil? ? sum = t : sum += t }
avg = sum / measurements.size

# 7 is the width reserved for the description "sum:" and "avg:"
Benchmark.bm(7, "sum:", "avg:") do |b|
  [sum, avg]
end
```

The result will look like the following:

```
             user     system      total        real
sum:     2.700000   0.000000   2.700000 (  2.706234)
avg:     0.270000   0.000000   0.270000 (  0.270623)
```

Comment: I just wish there was the shortcut for `require 'benchmark'; Benchmark.measure { ... }`

Comment: I don't understand, the quoted part is pretty short. What would you like to have? (Pseduo-Code allowed ;)

Comment: sure, probably can't get shorter than this, was just lamenting the lack of some shortcut provided with ruby by default to save typing. + I always forget is it `measure` or `bm` or `bmbm` or something else :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`Process::times`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Process.html#M001318) function, which returns user time/system time. (It does not report wall clock time, you'll need something else for that). Seems to be a bit version or OS dependent though.

This is what it reports on my system (linux, ruby 1.8.7):

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> t = Process.times
=> #<struct Struct::Tms utime=0.01, stime=0.0, cutime=0.0, cstime=0.0>
```

The docs show this though, so some versions/implementations might only have the first two:

```
t = Process.times
[ t.utime, t.stime ]   #=> [0.0, 0.02]
```

See [`times`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/times.2.html) for the underlying call on Linux.

Here's a really crappy wrapper that kind of supports `-`:

```
class SysTimes

    attr_accessor :user, :system

    def initialize
        times = Process.times
        @user = times.utime
        @system = times.stime
    end

    def -(other)
        diff = SysTimes.new
        diff.user = @user - other.user
        diff.system = @system - other.system
        diff
    end
end
```

Should give you ideas to make it work nicely in your context.

Comment: Sadly it's a struct which doesn't know how to respond to `-`, thus `time = Process.times ; user, system = Process.times - time` will raise an error. However, didn't know about this method before and I like the approach, since I may look up how long my program is running in any point of time. :) Thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

This gem might help:
https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/benchmark_methods

No more code like this:

```
t = Time.now
user.calculate_report
puts Time.now - t
```

Now you can do:

```
benchmark :calculate_report # in class
```

And just call your method

```
user.calculate_report
```